# How to map Right-Ctrl to Escape in LMDE?

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, linux-mint

Is it possible to map <kbd>Right</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> in Linux Mint Debian Edition?

Comment: I've got gnome as my wm, if that helps.

Comment: I've been here, but its not entirely clear.  :( http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_XWindows